# Preventing iframes containing target=“_blank” links from taking over the app

Tags: cordova, iframe, youtube-iframe-api

I am using Apache cordova platform to build hybrid mobile apps. I need to embed a youtube video into my application. Without any problem, I was able to embed a video in an Android device but the same thing is not working in IOS. After I added the following code snippet it's started working.

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" /> <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" /> <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

After successfully embedded video I faced an issue. If user click on the video title, entire space is occuping with video user don't have an option to go back to application. To access application user need's to re-open the app. To fix this tried following use-cases.

case 1: Tried with **showinfo** option from youtube embedded [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#showinfo). But unfortunately, that option got deprecated.

case2: Tried to hide the dom element by using CSS with the following snippet. but no luck. I defined styles on global level.

```
.ytp-show-cards-title {
display: none;
}
```

case3: Tried to find any Cordova plugins which can solve my problem, but didn't find any plugin.

I am ok to hide the entire title and options from the video or else any Cordova plugin which can open video in a browser on video title click.

Note: It's happening only in IOS, not in Android.

Thank you if someone can help on this.